# Android difficulty with linearlayout inside scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a problem with my layout, the last linearlayout doesn't seem to expand fully. FYI this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ihealthfirst"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/tabsfornutrition" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagefruits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/vegetables"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fruits_logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="35dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtApples"
            style="@style/NutritionText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.50" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btViewApples"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/viewnutritionalfacts" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descheader"
    style="@style/DescriptionHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="@string/description" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fruitDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]

If you could help me, I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" change to wrap_content

Comment: what textview are u referring to?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What is wrong with your screenshot?

Comment: my last linearlayout is not expanding to its full size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope u talking about the LinearLayout which has Description, first of all I think u r not clear with fill_parent / match_parent / wrap_content, why I'm thinking like this s,

U r setting height and width as fill_parent for both the include layout and also to the sibling Linearlayout.

> ```
> <includ
>   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent"
>   layout="@layout/tabsfornutrition" />
>
>
> <LinearLayout
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
> ```

but u not worry about one layout is overlaps another.

So pls go throw following structure, that will give you a clear understating.
I hope u need to fill the linearlayout which having the description, if not update your question clearly..

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ihealthfirst"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/tabsfornutrition" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagefruits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/vegetables"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fruits_logo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="35dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtApples"
                    style="@style/NutritionText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btViewApples"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/viewnutritionalfacts" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descheader"
                style="@style/DescriptionHeader"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/description" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fruitDesc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If you set `match_parent` on the first `LinearLayout` then the it makes no sense to put it in a `ScrollView`. The whole point of a `ScrollView` is to wrap a child that is bigger than itself...

Comment: so should he leave the ScrollView blank?

Answer (score 21):

Did you try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to your ScrollView layout ? (see Romain Guy's trick : http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/ )

Comment: just as the javafx's scrollPane

Answer (score 1):

The included `tabsfornutrition` element has a `layout_height` of `match_parent` and it is the first child of its parent, so it will obviously take all available space...

Try setting `wrap_content` instead, for this element and the one after:

```
<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/tabsfornutrition" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

Comment: still the same. My last linearlayout is not expanding. I tried using fillViewport but my last linearlayout has gone out of sight

Comment: What do you mean by "not expanding" ? Can you see the 2 text views of the last linear layout when you scroll ?

Comment: No i can't see the 2 textviews

Comment: Then I don't know what else to try...I just tested it with sample images/text and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

The LinearLayout (and the textViews) are set to wrap_content. Set the second LinearLayout to:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview for only one child define and first of all u define scrollview and then define relative layout and then whatever your require for layouts using.

Answer (score -2):

It's because you tell it to `wrap_content` in height. It should be `match_parent`.

Comment: what linearlayot are u referring to?